# own view controller template

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

here i want to ask a question regarding view controller template for iphone or ipad.

question: i want to design a view controller with some images and make it as common template and need to use it as a template to other view controller too. (also some buttons and labels are the inclusions if needed)

(ie) when ever i call that class, automatically its components should be inherited to calling class.

is it possible?

it would be grateful if anyone answers me the suitable or favourable

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how adMob works but like everything else you can create a BaseViewController in which you can add your adMob(in the viewDidLoad method) and then all the other viewControllers can subClass this BaseViewController. just call [super viewDidLoad]; in the viewDidLoad methods of your viewControllers and you will have it...

hoping this sorts your problem... :) this is what I usually do.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to derive your view controllers from a common base class. Is there something that you want to do that's not provided by inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

You need to create @property for your components to re use them in other class

**in class1:**

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *exercisesArray;
```

**in class2:**

```
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSMutableArray *array;
```

nextViewController *start = [[nextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"nextViewController" bundle:nil];

next.array = exercisesArray